# Script execution of host commands from docker for Mac using Socat

Tags: bash, docker, macos, pipe, socat

I have a SOCAT setup that allows me to break out of the docker container and execute commands on the host. I realize this defeats the purpose of the container, but I'm leveraging a CNAB tool that operates in a docker container for deploying an app that cannot run in a docker container. The setup looks like this:

#### Host Machine

```bash
#! /bin/bash
# listen for connections on port and pass to the shell

socat TCP-LISTEN:$PORT EXEC:/bin/bash
```

#### Container

```bash
socat TCP:host.docker.internal:$PORT -
```

Using the hyphen at the end will read from stdout and works without any issue. I need now to automate the commands that will be executed. My first thought was to create a pipe and then echo the commands to it.

```bash
socat PIPE:/relay.sock TCP:host.docker.internal:$PORT
```

When I try this, however, the pipe is unreliable, it doesn't always send the output to the TCP port, and sometimes the commands cause the host server to crash. I've tried using unix sockets created with socat and mounting them to the container, but this doesn't work at all, nor do `fifo` sockets ( A known issue with docker for desktop Mac edition)

So far my best option has been tcp sockets, but I can't find a reliable way to automate this.